# Concatenating black-list to use as AWK gsub regex in CSV file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I'm attempting to use a script to remove any occurrence of a string in a blacklist.txt file from a specific column in a CSV file.

Via many versions of trial and error I have found the following AWK regex to work without matching substrings.

Converting newline delimited txt file into regex:
`list="$(cat blacklist.txt | tr "\n" "|" | sed 's/.$//')"`

This gives an output akin to this:
`already|also|although|always|am|among|amongst|amoungst|amount|an|and|another|any|anyhow|anyone|anything|anyway|anywhere`

Then I attempt to use this variable in an awk replacement command, using `"\\<(word|word)>\\ *"` regular expression format in order to avoid substring matches.

This looks as follows:

```
awk -F, -v list=$list 'BEGIN{ re = "\x22\\\\<("list")\\\\> *\x22"} { gsub(re,"", $2);} 1 ' OFS=',' test.csv
```

This itself does not work. However, if I print the regular expression generated from this command:

```
awk -F, -v list=$list 'BEGIN{ re = "\x22\\\\<("list")\\\\> *\x22"} { gsub(re,"", $2); print re} 1 ' OFS=',' test.csv
```

I get an output of `re` in the format:

```
"\\<(a|about|above|across|after|afterwards|again|against|all|almost|alone|along|already|also|although|always|am|among|amongst|amoungst|amount|an|and|another|any|anyhow|anyone|anything|anyway|anywhere)\\> *"
```

If I copy this and paste it into the awk command replacing the `re` variable in the gsub then it works!

I can't work out why the regular expression doesn't work as a variable, when the direct output of the variable pasted in as a regular expression does work.

## Sample CSV

```
foobar,a house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,a house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,a house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,a house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
```

## Incorrect output from command using variable

```
awk -F, -v list=$list 'BEGIN{ re = "\x22\\\\<("list")\\\\> *\x22"} { gsub(re,"", $2);} 1 ' OFS=',' test.csv
```

```
foobar,a house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,a house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,a house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,a house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
```

## Correct output from command using contents of variable

```
awk -F, -v list=$stop_word_list '{ gsub("\\<(a|about|above|across|after|afterwards|again|against|all|almost|alone|along|already|also|although|always|am|among|amongst|amoungst|amount|an|and|another|any|anyhow|anyone|anything|anyway|anywhere)\\> *","", $2);} 1 ' OFS=',' test.csv
```

```
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
```

Note that 'a' is gone from the second column but not the third, and the a inside 'car' is not matched either.

Note that the blacklist.txt file is somewhat longer than what I supplied here, and I do not have the option of hard-coding in the blacklisted words as they may be swapped out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OP's code the `re = "\x22...\x22"` is embedding actual double quotes in the variable `re` which in turn is telling `gsub()` to look for actual double quotes in `$2`.

While stripping the `\x22` will likely help, I'm going to opt for a slightly different approach ...

---

One `awk` solution that builds the regex within the `gsub()` call:

```
list='a|about|above|across|after'

awk -v list="${list}" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {gsub("\\<("list")\\> *","",$2)} 1' test.csv
```

This generates:

```
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
```

---

If the OP needs the regex in a few places, we can still build the `re` variable with the following:

```
awk -v list="${list}" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","; re="\\<("list")\\> *"} {gsub(re,"",$2)} 1' test.csv
```

Which also generates:

```
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
foobar,house car,a foobar, foobar foobar
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried both those something similar to both those variations but I used `list=$list` over `list="${list}"`. Really appreciated!

Comment: There must have been something else a bit different since `list=$list` does work in this case

Comment: Just to clear up the first bit, "\x22" is the hex ascii code for a double quotation mark, I used it to get as close to the manual regex as possible.